# HTML5 Javascript image positioning

Tags: javascript, html

My question should have a simple answer, but I am very frustrated because the situation is not logical to me. What I am trying to do is put a top margin on an image on a screen. It works without a DOCTYPE line, but does not with it in place to enable HTML5.

[Good]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Question</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="help.jpg" id="img1" style="position:absolute">
        <script>
            document.getElementById("img1").style.top = 50;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Bad]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Question</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="help.jpg" id="img1" style="position:absolute">
        <script>
            document.getElementById("img1").style.top = 50;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The good example only gives 50 pixels of top margin to the image. The only difference is the absence and existence of the first `DOCTYPE` line. `help.jpg` is a local image file. I get the same behavior for Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: Thank you for all who kindly pointed out what was wrong in my code! I successfully corrected the error, and now am able to come back to my work. I thought that the unit in pixel is default, and so it can be omitted. There still remain some doubt why the behavior is different for HTML5, though...

Answer (score 0):

Add pixels to the property style like

```
document.getElementById("img1").style.top = "50px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a unit. Try:

```
document.getElementById("img1").style.top = '50px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct output where the code is working.U have to use the quotes as well as units in the script.

document.getElementById("img1").style.top = "50px";